# Verify the existence of a twitter account using AJAX/JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter

I am trying to build a simple check that will accept a string and check to see if a twitter account exists by that string.

I have successfully managed to get a positive result, but I can't seem to get a negative one. `$.ajax()` has an error element, but it is not firing.

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/bVds7/)

Code:

```
var testTwit = function(username){
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name='+username+'&count=1&callback=?',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(){
          alert("username is valid");
      }, 
     error: function(){
         alert("username is valid");
     }
   })
 }
```

​

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a summarize of **[arnaud576875](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12261305/266561)**'s answer:

1. Add a `suppress_response_codes=1` parameter
2. Check for `ID` returned

So, the result will be something like this:

```
var testTwit = function(username){
    $.ajax({
       url: 'http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline.json?suppress_response_codes=1&screen_name='+username+'&count=1&callback=?',
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function(d){
         if (d && d.id)    
            $('span').html('username is valid!');
         else
            $('span').html('username is not valid.');
       }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using the JSONP transport. In this transport, the requested URL is simply added as a `<script>` tag in the document. If the URL returns a non-200 status code, the browser won't execute it: that's why you can't see negative responses.

One solution is to use the `suppress_response_codes` parameter, so that the API always return a 200 status code.

See [Things Every Twitter Developer Should Know](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/things-every-developer-should-know):

> - `suppress_response_codes`: If this parameter is present, all responses will be returned with a 200 OK status code - even errors. This parameter exists to accommodate Flash and JavaScript applications running in browsers that intercept all non-200 responses. If used, it’s then the job of the client to determine error states by parsing the response body. Use with caution, as those error messages may change.

BTW, Twitter is suppressing non-authenticated access to the API, so JSONP access may be suppressed too.

Answer (score 0):

Usually API's always returns a response when a request is received. That's why no error is given. You should parse the response coming from the API to find out if a user exists or not.

Answer (score 0):

Errors are not triggered when using JSONP-requests. Read more at [jQuery Forums](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-ajax-with-datatype-jsonp-will-not-use-error-callback-if-request-fails).